# OracleSQL compare to dates based on integer columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am given a HUGE table with two columns, `date6`, `date8` that contain dates stored as integers. Unfortunately, one is 6 digits, and one is 8 digits, i.e. `date6` could be `201002` for February 2010, and `date8` could be `20100205` for 5th February 2010.

I am trying to do `WHERE` operations, for example keeping only observations when the two dates match, or keeping only observations if `date6` is the previous month of `date8`. Being somewhat new to SQL, I am trying to piece together what I need and any advice is greatly appreciated.

Working with Orcacle 12.1.0

Comment: Refer to chapter 7 (Functions) in [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions.htm#SQLRF006) which is part of Oracle 12c database documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `WHERE` clause

```
where 
   -- checks for the same date
   to_date(date6,'yyyymm') = trunc( to_Date(date8,'yyyymmdd') , 'MON')  
   -- checks if date6 is previous month of date8
   or to_date(date6,'yyyymm') = trunc(add_months(to_Date(date8,'yyyymmdd'), - 1),'MON')
```

Comment: thanks for this. The first should be `to_date(date6,'yyyymm') =trunc( to_Date(date8,'yyyymmdd') , 'MON')`

Comment: Ok, WIll change it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view and put inside `date6` and `date8` in the format you wish to use using the `to_date` command  that way `date6` and `date8` will both be on the same format and you will be able to compare them.